imagemagick pipe to ffmpeg
I'm trying to write a batch file for a friend to make timelapse videos. I'm using avisynth, but she's even more clueless than I, so I tried to do most of the work with ffmpeg.
What I'd like to do is to pipe imagemagick output (a filtered sequence of jpeg images) to ffmpeg and create a video.
I've thrown out everything out of the batch file, and more or less here i am:
magick jpg:- d:\54tldir\src\*.jpg | ffmpeg.exe -f image2pipe -i pipe: -c:v libx264 02video.mp4

I'm sure I've missed 1 or a few or many things.
all help would be appreciated - on my level (very low).

I cleaned up your text a little. Keep in mind that you write this for other people to read.

What is the purpose of Imagemagick here? I'm not familiar with Windows command line, but can't you use the glob in the FFmpeg call directly?

I'm with @AkselA here. What's the point of ImageMagick here?

hiya, first, thanks. as ive written before ive tried to clean it up to lessen the chance of making mistakes. '-normalize -auto-gamma' would be the imagemagick options.

Try magick d:\54tldir\src\*.jpg -normalize -auto-gamma jpg:- | ffmpeg ... because the general form is magick INPUT ...process... OUTPUT and consider which are your input files and what format you want the output files.

thank you sir! this seems to be working. however... it takes up a ton of memory (even swap with 16gb of ram), and it creates 167mb temporary files. most of the time is spent with hdd writing. i hoped that piping works in memory, imagemagick does its thing and the feeds it to ffmpeg. i guess back to the original idea: make temp files with im and feed them to fffmpeg. id still appreciate a viable, losslessly compressed temp format however... thanks again!

I don't know if it would help the performance or quality in your situation, but I've always piped ImageMagick output to ffmpeg by using "png:-".

Rather than read all your files into ImageMagick at once, you could do them one at a time to save memory (RAM). Not 100% sure of Windows syntax, but it will probably look like this roughly:
 ( FOR /F %g IN (D:\54tldr\src\*.jpg) DO magick %g -normalize -auto-gamma JPEG:- ) | ffmpeg ...


Under macOS or Linux, it would be:
for f in *.jpg; do
  magick "$f" -normalize -auto-level JPEG:-
done | ffmpeg ...


If we can't get my pathetic Windows BATCH script working, you can make a script manually like this:
DIR /B D:\54tldir\src\*.jpg > script.bat

and you will get a file called script.bat that contains something like:
D:\54tldr\src\1.jpg
D:\54tldr\src\2.jpg
D:\54tldr\src\3.jpg

Load that into an editor, and add some magic to each line so it looks like:
magick D:\54tldr\src\1.jpg -normalize -auto-gamma JPEG:-
magick D:\54tldr\src\2.jpg -normalize -auto-gamma JPEG:-
magick D:\54tldr\src\3.jpg -normalize -auto-gamma JPEG:-

Then you should be able to do:
script.bat | ffmpeg ...


Consider not re-compressing the images to JPEG. You'll lose some fidelity, and spend extra time/resources on compressing/de-compressing. IM's TIFF export is uncompressed by default, and FFmpeg can handle TIFF input. This will require more temporary storage, so make sure you have the necessary disk space (~3MB per MP).

@AkselA The mp4 output format that OP has selected is also compressed so OP is presumably happy with some loss of quality. TIFF is potentially better but could be overkill and may use 6MB per MP if OP is using Q16 ImageMagick. My answer doesn't write any intermediate files to disk, btw - all data transfers are via a pipe.

I didn't look clearly enough at the loop, I see now how it works. Transcoding via JPEG will still lose quality compared to going directly to H.264, you're increasing the generation loss, and now with even less benefit.

dear sirs, i thank you all for your time and effort to help. i do try to to do all intermediate stuff losslessly (a pet peeve of mine). now i dont have the time, but i will definitely play around according to your fine advices, and report back. thanks again, g

You can simply change JPEG:- to PNG:- or TIFF:- throughout to go lossless if you prefer that.

ANY solution would be preferable to the ones ive tried so far: piping from imagemagick to ffmpeg (creates uncompressed, 167mb temp files for all of the frames) and, more viable, but far from perfect, create compressed lossless images for all the frames. @12mpixels/frame the latter results in ~15mb/frame (webp/jp2). 450mb/sec, ~27gb/min. now, thats a lot. for my stuff i generally try not to make longer than 1,5-2,5 minutes of timelapse (it gets boring after that), and i have enough hdd space. but i know that my friend has a laptop, and trying for a 5 minute long video - it would take 150gb.

and anyway, for my stuff i use aviynth which does everything i need. but for my friend i try to make a simple resolution with a simple command line solution in batch script, all software preinstalled, "portable". if it works, the command line would be xxx.cmd yyyyy, where yyyyy is the number of frames.

Mark, i do appreciate your contribution. but as far as i understand the same could be achieved with an imagemagick command - making a ton of intermediate files (whether jpg, png or smthing other) and feed them to ffmpeg. it seems that there are 4 options: feed (pipe) enhanced photos directly to ffmpeg OR create some lossless intermediate images OR make lossy intermediate pictures OR throw away the whole pic enhancement stuff...
